# Python Dictionary, make range associated with its values and return them

Tags: python-3.x

Say, I have a dictionary

```
 D = {'A':0.25,'C':0.25,'G':0.25,'T':0.25}
```

The sum of dictionary values will always be one. I want to make range for each keys in D that would be as follows:

- The first key : `(0, D[FirstKey])`.
- The second key `(SecondRangeParameterOfFirstKey, SecondRangeParameterOfFirstKey + ValueOfSecondKey)` that is `(0.25,0.50)`.
- The third key would be as `( SecondRangeParameterOfSecondKey,SecondRangeParameterOfSecondKey + ValueOfSecondKey)` that is `(0.50,0.75)`.
- The range for the fourth key would be `(0.75,1)`.

One thing is last parameter of range for last key will always be 1 that is the summation of all values together.

I generate a random float between 0 and 1. I need to return the key following random float . So for example, for the given order of dictionary D, if I generate `0.63` then I have to return third key that is G because its range is `(0.50,0.75)`. As dictionary is not ordered so I have to count range following dictionary's order and return that return the key following order of dictionary. So far I coded for this problem as following:

```
import random
def W(D):
    vv = 0
    f = 0
    mer = ''
    ran = random.uniform(0,1)
    DI = D.items()
    for k,v in DI:
        mer = ''
        if (ran >= f) and (ran < D[k]+vv):
            mer = k
            vv += v
return mer
```

My function never returns the third key when floats are generated that fall in third keys range that is `(0.50,0.75)`, it returns fourth key instead.

Comment: You only generate one random number? Also dicts are unordered so there is no idea of a first key unless you sort the data

Comment: Each run of this function, I generate only one random float.

Comment: So you want the closest value under the random float value? Why are the values not stored as the upper bound and what is your idea of the first key?

Comment: I do not get your words.

Comment: What is a first key?  Is it based on value, key .. Are the values always equal i.e if you have 10 keys there are all .10? You say *for the given order of dictionary D* but dicts are unordered so that does not make sense

Comment: Values are not always equal but the total sum of values will be always 1. Yes, dicts are unordered. I wanted to mean, everytime I run the code for same dicts its order will not be ordered.

Comment: Will the values always be the same, just the keys changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dicts are unordered so if you want maintain some order you will need an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), this will find the key in the range based on increasing ranges on key order, this requires you to add the keys ordered by value:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict((('A', 0.25), ('C', 0.25), ('G',0.25), ('T', 0.25)))

def W(od):
    ran = random.uniform(0, 1)
    tot = 0
    for k, v in od.items():
        if tot <= ran < v + tot:
            return k
        tot += v
```

Adding a `print(ran, v,  tot + v)` in the loop:

```
In [36]: W(od)
0.13237220509287917 0.25 0.25
Out[36]: 'A'

In [37]: W(od)
0.22239648741773488 0.25 0.25
Out[37]: 'A'

In [38]: W(od)
0.2798873944681526 0.25 0.25
0.2798873944681526 0.25 0.5
Out[38]: 'C'

In [39]: W(od)
0.05933372630532163 0.25 0.25
Out[39]: 'A'

In [40]: W(od)
0.776438095223963 0.25 0.25
0.776438095223963 0.25 0.5
0.776438095223963 0.25 0.75
0.776438095223963 0.25 1.0
Out[40]: 'T'
```

If the values are not all the same you will need to sort, you can use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the key to sort the items by value:

```
from operator import itemgetter
d = {'A': 0.35, 'C': 0.2, 'T': 0.3, 'G': 0.15}

def W(d):
    ran = random.uniform(0, 1)
    tot = 0
    # sort from lowest value to highest
    for k, v in sorted(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1)):
        if tot <= ran < v + tot:
            return k
        tot += v
```

Adding a print again:

```
In [55]: W(d)
0.15 0.24005200696606188 0.15
0.2 0.24005200696606188 0.35
Out[55]: 'C'

In [56]: W(d)
0.15 0.9860872247496385 0.15
0.2 0.9860872247496385 0.35
0.3 0.9860872247496385 0.6499999999999999
0.35 0.9860872247496385 0.9999999999999999
Out[56]: 'A'

In [57]: W(d)
0.15 0.5690026436736583 0.15
0.2 0.5690026436736583 0.35
0.3 0.5690026436736583 0.6499999999999999
Out[57]: 'T'

In [58]: W(d)
0.15 0.28507671431234327 0.15
0.2 0.28507671431234327 0.35
Out[58]: 'C'
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind look at my problem. You are nearly I have expected to do but I just need start v from 0, for first iteration it will be 0, second iteration it will be 0.25, third iteration it will be 0.50 and for last it will be 0.75. I do not want to multiply here, instead at second iteration the value of v would be the tot+v value from first iteration, at third v would be the value of tot+v from second iteration, so v is 0.50 and at last will be 0.75

Comment: @DumbCoder,  there is no multiplication here, all we are doing is adding accumulating the total going from the  lowest to highest values

Comment: Thanks, you saved my another day. It returns exactly what I want but gives wrong answer where I need to apply this function. I think I misinterpreted requirements.

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I need to know about collections and operator module. I think such modules would save my time. Please suggest me some links about them I can learn something new.

Comment: @DumbCoder, no worries, I added the links to the documentation

Comment: Where I can find the documentation?

Comment: Just click on the highlighted links